# is there any command to "terminate all other sessions" in telegram-cli?

Tags: python, telegram

i need a script to terminate all other sessions each time new login in my account detected(or each second) in python. **is there any command to "terminate all other sessions" in telegram-cli?**

Comment: Seriously, why was this question down-voted?

Comment: see my answer below, but i dont know if your current CLI supports this. however you can add it yourself possibly. The required commands and expected responses are in my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need the session_id of your other sessions:

```
destroy_session#e7512126 session_id:long = DestroySessionRes;The expected
```

responses is:

```
destroy_session_ok#e22045fc session_id:long = DestroySessionRes;
```

or

```
destroy_session_none#62d350c9 session_id:long = DestroySessionRes;
```